# set +a does not unset the -a flag

Tags: bash, environment-variables

On Mac 10.11.6, using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) the `set +a` command appears to not work:

`script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print("VAR0 is:", os.environ.get("VAR0")
```

Commands:

```
$ VAR0=abc
$ ./script.py
('VAR0 is:', None)   # expected
$ set -a
$ VAR0=abc
$ ./script.py
('VAR0 is:', 'abc')   # expected, VAR0 has been exported to the environment and script.py has access to it
$ set +a
$ VAR0=def
$ ./script.py
('VAR0 is:', 'def')   # <= unexpected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take away: Yes, `set +a` unsets `set -a` but variables do not become un exported because of that. Each variable then needs to be un exported or unset.

---

The option `allexport` (Same as `set -a`) allows for automatic export of **new** and **changed** variables. Variables that exist before activating the `set -a` option will not be exported.

Two points before testing:

1. The condition of `set -a` could be printed with `shopt -po allexport`.
   And could be changed with `shopt -os allexport` and `shopt -ou allexport`.

   ```
   $ shopt -po allexport
   set +o allexport

   $ set -a
   $ shopt -po allexport
   set -o allexport

   $ set +a
   $ shopt -po allexport
   set +o allexport
   ```
2. The shell way to test environment variables is to examine the output of the `environment` command, actually to `grep` it

   ```
   $ env | grep PATH
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
   ```

No need for an external program from python (that needs compiling on first call). You may still use it if that makes you happy, but there is no real need for that.

If the option is unset (`set +a`). A **new** variable will **not** be exported.

```
$ unset VAR0
$ VAR0=abc
$ env | grep VAR0
                      # nothing is printed.
```

Or, if you still want your program:

```
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is: None
```

If the `-a` option is changed, the var will not be exported until changed:

```
$ set -a
$ shopt -po allexport
set -o allexport
$ env | grep VAR0
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is: None
```

If the variable change:

```
$ VAR0=bcd
$ env | grep VAR0
VAR0=bcd
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is: bcd
```

But the variable will remain in the environment if the `set +a` is applied:

```
$ set +a
$ env | grep VAR0
VAR0=bcd
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is: bcd
```

Even if the var is changed, it is still part of the environment:

```
$ VAR0=xyz
$ env | grep VAR0
VAR0=xyz
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is: xyz
```

Until it is either un exported (remove the export attribute):

```
$ declare +x VAR0
```

Or it is simply `unset`

```
$ env | grep VAR0
VAR0=xyz
$ unset VAR0
$ env | grep VAR0
```

No, assigning an empty value is not the same:

```
$ VAR0=''
$ env | grep VAR0
VAR0=
```

Which your program doesn't show that clearly:

```
$ ./envtest.py
VAR0 is:
```

Answer (score 5):

You've misunderstood what `set -a` does. If a variable is exported, changes to that variable are always reflected to the environment. (This wasn't always true of historical implementations of `sh`, but it's true in all modern, POSIX-compliant(-ish) shells.) The `-a` option only forces a variable to be exported even if it wasn't before: by default an assignment creates a shell variable, but when `-a` is in effect the assignment causes the variable to be exported even if it wasn't already.

`set +a` does unset the `-a` option. Changing the value of an exported variable affects the environment whether `-a` is in effect or not.

Comment: Not only when a variable becomes **defined** but also when a variable is **modified** (I am talking of what becomes exported if the -a option is in effect, of course)..

Comment: For clarity, since `VAR0` in the question was *set* while `set -a` was in effect, it was exported and thus stayed that way; even modifications made to it after `set +a` was called will still modify the exported variable and thus be visible. The "modification" part means that if `VAR0` were *defined* while `set +a` were in effect (and thus it wasn't exported) but was *modified* after `set -a` was called, VAR0 would *get* exported upon the modification (and stay that way even if `set +a` is called again).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the assignment to the local shell variable is now affecting the environment variable.  If you first unset the variable then future assignments only work on the local shell variable as before:

```
$ unset VAR0
$ VAR0=def
$ ./script.py
('VAR0 is:', 'None')
```